# How to create a new variable based on the fourth observation of a different variable

Tags: python, pandas

From this table

```
   ID, Date,  Value
    A    Jan01     5      
    A    Feb01     10     
    A    Mar03     9      
    A    Apr02     7      
    A    Jan01     2      
    B    Feb01     3      
    B    Mar01     6   
    B    Mar01     9    
    B    Mar02     5
```

Desired table:

```
  ID, Date,  Value, New_Variable
   A    Jan01     5      7
   A    Feb01     10     7
   A    Mar03     9      7
   A    Apr02     7      7
   A    Jan01     2      5
   B    Feb01     3      5
   B    Mar01     6      5
   B    Mar01     9      5
   B    Mar02     5      5
```

I know I can do

```
df.groupby('ID')['Value'].transform('first')
```

if I want to take the first value, what about the other rows? like the fourth or the fifth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group the datframe by `ID` then `transform` the `Value` column with **[`nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html)** to select the nth value from each group.

```
df['new_col'] = df.groupby('ID')['Value'].transform('nth', n=3)
```

---

```
print(df)

  ID   Date  Value  new_col
0  A  Jan01      5        7
1  A  Feb01     10        7
2  A  Mar03      9        7
3  A  Apr02      7        7
4  A  Jan01      2        7
5  B  Feb01      3        5
6  B  Mar01      6        5
7  B  Mar01      9        5
8  B  Mar02      5        5
```

Note: The `n` value is zero based, so in order to select the `4th` row you have to specify `n=3`

Comment: Yes!! this. Thanks!! knew it had to be simple. thanks :)

Comment: @Olivia Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

one idea is add a ranking column to show which place a row is in among its group. For example:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount()
```

In this case you know the 4th place for each ID.

```
fourth_place = df[df['rank']==3]
```

so that you can create a mapping

```
mapping = fourth_place.set_index('ID')['Value']
```

which can be used in creating the new column

```
df['New_Variable'] = df['ID'].map(mapping)
```

Comment: Thanks Raymond. Is there no simple way to add a line after "transform"??  This seems like so many steps for a seemingly simple idea.

Comment: @Shubham Sharma has proposed it!